# How to install newer mesa to support opengl 3.x in centos 7.6?

Tags: centos, opengl, mesa

Currently,

```
glxinfo|grep "OpenGL version"
```

gives

```
OpenGL version string: 4.6 Mesa 18.3.4
```

And

```
mesa-libGL-devel-18.3.4-12.el17_9.x86_64
```

got installed by default, but my app needs OpenGL 3.2 support at least.

Is possible to install newer mesa to support OpenGL 3.x? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: OpenGL 4.6 is the newest version of the OpenGL standard. It is **not older** than 3.2.

Comment: @SeetheMoar Thanks,what do you mean?

Comment: Look at the version string. It has `OpenGL version string: 4.6` at the beginning. which means that you have version 4.6 of OpenGL standard or `OpenGL version 4.6`. Since you need `version 3.2` which is older than 4.6, you can try executing/compiling your application using the version present on your machine, as OpenGL versions are generally backwards compatible. Also, semantics-wise, you cannot install a newer version of mesa, you have to use an older version of mesa.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw I am running RHEL 7.9 and

- if you are RHEL 7.6 my first thought would be to do a `yum update` to move to RHEL 7.9 along with the latest mesa; my system yum updated as of today reports `OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 510.47.03`.  **But I have `cuda_11.6.1_510.47.03_linux.run` installed.**
- on a rhel 7.9 test pc with no nvidia, glxinfo currently reports `3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 18.3.4.`

however long ago in getting linux to work with vnc and fix [commercial] software programs complaining about OpenGL and falling back to software rendering I put the following two items in an `/etc/profile.d/mesa_custom.sh`

```
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3
export MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=330
```

this seemed to satisfy various [commercial] software checks where it would often spit out a mesa or GL or software rendering warning and not run properly.

Any `.sh` file under `/etc/profile.d/` will get upon login for any user, so rename `mesa_custom` to your liking, just keep a `.sh` suffix; .sh for bash shells, .csh for csh and tcsh logins, and so on.  So it's a convenient global way to implement that a user doesn't have to worry about doing themself.

Comment: thanks,after run "yum update",nothing got updated

Comment: then that likely means you're system is  not registered with redhat and the `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` file is empty.  And if that is the case it may be beneficial for you to use CentOS instead of RHEL.